# Integration between Nodejs/ElectronJs and Zebra Printer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, zebra-printers

I am trying to make an integration between a nodeJs/electronJS app and a Printer Zebra gc420t, and i don't know how do that correctly.

I make a label (800x250 px) on html and send to print on a label 8x2.5 cm.

Te problem is the printer print a label correctly but it eject a blank label or a part of the blank label.

I create a new window and load de code, then I print the window:

```
ipcMain.on('printLabel', (event, arg) => {


 labelWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false });
  const html = `<html><head></head><body><style type="text/css" media="print">@page{size: 25mm 80mm landscape ;margin: 0; }</style>${arg.label}</body></html>`;

  labelWindow.loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(arg.label));
  labelWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    options = {
      silent: true,
      printBackground: false,
      deviceName: arg.printer,
      margins: { marginType: 'none'},
      scaleFactor: 35,
      pageSize: { height: 25000, width: 80000 }
    };
    labelWindow.webContents.print(options, () => {
      labelWindow.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I had a similar problem saving a webpage to pdf where the file was clipped at a certain point. My issue was that the HTML was overflowing the screen. I see that the label size is quite small, but perhaps it's a similar issue?